# Multiple Copies of Image Fader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code fades a set of images in individual div's that are within the "slideshow" div and works perfectly. The thing is that it only works for one set of images. Just wondering if there is any way possible to create a "slideshow2" div and have that set of images fade through as well. Any input would be greatly apreciated.

```
    $(function() {

        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() { 
          $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        },  3000);

    });
```

Comment: Use class for both slideshows...

Comment: It'll be a lot easier to help if we see your DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can do it this way( to not write the same code again):

```
$(function() {
    fade_function("#slideshow");
});


function fade_function(div_id)
{
   $(div_id+" > div:gt(0)").hide();
   setInterval(function() { 
      $(div_id+' > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo(div_id);
    },  3000);
}
```

and whenever you need call fade_function("your_div_here");

Answer (score 0):

Give both your slideshow divs the same class, something like `.slideshows` .
Then ammend your code as follows...

$(function() {

```
    $(".slideshows > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
      $('.slideshows > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('.slideshows');
    },  3000);

});
```

That way your code will execute for both slideshows at once, without having to use seperate functions. :)

Comment: Thankyou very much! I have not had time to test it just yet but it makes so much sense and can't believe I didn't see that earlier. Cheers :)

Comment: a pleasure my friend! :) Good luck with it! :)

Comment: On trying this I found that it did not work properly :( It simple cycled through the images that were in the first set of images on all the rest and only had the fading functionality on the first one.

Thank's for your ideas though :)